# Sending a vector by chunks from one thread to another using mpsc channel

Tags: rust

I am trying to send a vector by chunks from one thread to another by using rust `std::mpsc::channel`. But the Rust compiler is producing a lifetime error.

Here is the relevant code:

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread;
use rand::Rng;

const NUM_REQUESTS: u64 = 1 << 20;
const BATCH_SIZE: u64 = 32;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    let mut threads = vec![];
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut requests = vec![];

    for _ in 0..NUM_REQUESTS {
        requests.push(rng.gen::<u64>());
    }

    threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
        // Send 32 requests slice at a time
        for chunk in requests.chunks(BATCH_SIZE as usize) {
            tx.send(chunk).unwrap();
        }

        drop(tx);
    }));

    threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
        while let Ok(chunk) = rx.recv() {
            println!("Got: {:?}", chunk);
        }
    }));

    for t in threads {
        t.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Here is the error the rust compiler is producing:

```
error[E0597]: `requests` does not live long enough
  --> server/benches/queuebench.rs:20:22
   |
9  |     let (tx, rx) = channel();
   |          -- lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `tx`
...
12 |     let mut requests = vec![];
   |         ------------ binding `requests` declared here
...
20 |         for chunk in requests.chunks(BATCH_SIZE as usize) {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
21 |             tx.send(chunk).unwrap();
   |             -------------- argument requires that `requests` is borrowed for `'1`
...
25 |     }));
   |     - `requests` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `server` (bench "queuebench") due to 1 previous error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::thread::spawn` requires its parameter to be `'static`, so it can't borrow data that will be dropped at the end of `main`, which `rx` does. But this can be solved with [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html), which remove the `'static` requirement by providing an interface that always joins all threads before returning.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut requests = vec![];
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    for _ in 0..NUM_REQUESTS {
        requests.push(rng.gen::<u64>());
    }

    thread::scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(|| {
            for chunk in requests.chunks(BATCH_SIZE as usize) {
                tx.send(chunk).unwrap();
            }
            drop(tx);
        });

        scope.spawn(move || {
            while let Ok(chunk) = rx.recv() {
                println!("Got: {:?}", chunk);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This can be cleaned up a bit.

```rust
fn main() {
    // use the sample_iter interface of rand to construct the vec directly
    let requests: Vec<u64> = rand::thread_rng()
        .sample_iter(rand::distributions::Standard)
        .take(NUM_REQUESTS as usize)
        .collect();
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    thread::scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(|| {
            for chunk in requests.chunks(BATCH_SIZE as usize) {
                tx.send(chunk).unwrap();
            }
            drop(tx);
        });

        // use the main thread for the final task
        while let Ok(chunk) = rx.recv() {
            println!("Got: {:?}", chunk);
        }
    });
}
```

This is equivalent to what you wrote, but if you're trying to send each chunk to its own thread, scoped threads allow you to do that without the channel.

Comment: My understanding is that `'static` isn't the issue here. As, I am waiting for both of the threads to be finished before the end of `main`. So, there is no way spawned threads will outlive `main`.

After posting this, I have found the main issue (in my view). I am sending a reference of `requests` through `chunk` from one thread to another. If I send a copy instead it compiles happily. If I change the sender loop to add `let chunk: Vec<_> = requests[start..end].iter().cloned().collect();` it compiles just fine.

I guess the scoped solution is better as it is more performant than cloning?

Comment: Waiting for the threads is not considered here, since a) it would mean some kind of interprocedural analysis (considering both `spawn` and `join`), b) it would break in case of panics.

Comment: @AshfaqurRahaman I want to be clear, this isn't about `requests` and it's not really about threads. Any function that requires `'static` cannot be passed a borrow of local data. This is overly conservative for `std::thread::spawn` but rust was designed with the idea that this restriction is a reasonable compromise that allows statically checking for memory safety. As for `requests`, it is fine. It doesn't borrow anything. `rx` is what borrows, and by changing its type from `Receiver<&[u64]>` to `Receiver<Vec<u64>>`, you are removing the borrow. Same for `tx`.